# Does Instagram API have collections endpoint?

Tags: instagram-api

I could not find any documentation for accessing instagram collections. Is there a way to query user's collections? If not, how can I learn if it is a planned feature for future?

Comment: there is no API for collection as of now, they are not updating APIs with new feature for a while now...